# Objective-C: TableView in UIViewController - Data just load after a click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, tableview

I have a table view in a UIViewController and I load the data from a database. But when I start the app the table is empty. Only when I click on the table the data will appear. Can someone tell me what I must change? Here is my code:

```
#import "DashboardViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DashboardViewController () 

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *data;

@end

@implementation DashboardViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self data]; // ???
}

- (NSMutableArray *)data {

    if(!_data){

        _data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSString *username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"username"];

        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.net/getData.php?user=%@", username];
        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

            NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            NSString *errorCode = [json valueForKey:@"error"];

            if([errorCode isEqualToString:@"e0"]){

                NSArray *myData = [json objectForKey:@"myData"];

                for (int i = 0; i < [myData count]; i++) {
                    [_data addObject:[myData objectAtIndex:i]];
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                }

            }

        }];

        [dataTask resume];

    }

    return _data;

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.data count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: just write [self.tableView reloadData]; out of your loop and if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not like

```
for (int i = 0; i < [myData count]; i++) {
                [_data addObject:[myData objectAtIndex:i]];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }
```

do like

> 

```
 for (int i = 0; i < [myData count]; i++) {
                [_data addObject:[myData objectAtIndex:i]];

            }

          if (_data.count>0)
         {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates
          [self.tableView reloadData];
      });
        }
```

Comment: you need to take your UI for main thread, the reason you added the another thread in main `dataTaskWithURL, so if we use `dispatch_get_main_queue` , it automattically populated teh list

Comment: Ty. One more question: I have a button on that view with a push segue. When I click on that button and then use the back button, how can I reload the data of the table view? I mean it should load the data from the database again. Do you know that?

Comment: call your data load method in ViewWillAppear

Comment: You mean [self.tableView reloadData];? Didn't work :/

Comment: no no bro, if you use that it clear all your data , where you called this method - (NSMutableArray *)data, you need to call this method in viewwillapear

Comment: I think im not sure what you mean. I tried [self data]; and [self.tableView reloadData]; in viewwillappear. But didn't work with both. Or what must I write now in viewwillappear?

Comment: You mean I should edit my code above with the viewwillappear? Done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120236/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-nono).